# How do I carry over a URL portion from source to destination in a RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have an httpd.conf file in which we place all our redirect rules for our www.towerswatson.com website.  We have many redirect rules such as the below:

RewriteRule ^/events/22037(/?)$ https://events.towerswatson.com/events/tool/render.asp?evtid=22037&cid=1&country=global&page=&isapi=on [NC,R=301,L]

That basically redirects www.towerswatson.com/events/22037 to https://events.towerswatson.com/events/tool/render.asp?evtid=22037&cid=1&country=global&page=&isapi=on.

Now what we want to do is make a generic redirect so that instead of having '22037' event ID in the above URL, we want to redirect ANY eventID www.towerswatson.com/events/EVENTID to https://events.towerswatson.com/events/tool/render.asp?evtid=EVENTID&cid=1&country=global&page=&isapi=on.

So maybe something like this:

RewriteRule ^/events/[eventid](/?)$ https://events.towerswatson.com/events/tool/render.asp?evtid=[eventid]&cid=1&country=global&page=&isapi=on [NC,R=301,L]

This way www.towerswatson.com/events/1234567 will redirect to https://events.towerswatson.com/events/tool/render.asp?evtid=1234567&cid=1&country=global&page=&isapi=on.

Is that correct?  How do I do that?  Please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

`RewriteRule ^/events/([0-9]+)/?$ https://events.towerswatson.com/events/tool/render.asp?evtid=$1&cid=1&country=global&page=&isapi=on`